# How to get Phoenix to listen on IPv6?

Tags: ipv6, phoenix-framework, cowboy

I'm struggling to find information about getting Phoenix (and Cowboy and Ranch for that matter) to listen on both IPv4 and IPv6.

I'm running on a VPS with Ubuntu 16.04. It has both an IPv4 and IPv6 address.
When running `netstat -tulpn` it shows that `beam` is only listening on IPv4, with the ports specified in Phoenix config.
Whereas other processes, like `epmd`, are able to listen on both IPv4 and IPv6.

I've tried specifying a port like `"::4000"` in my `config.exs`, but it crashes due to failure to parse as an integer.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Do I need to add a custom Cowboy listener somehow?

I'd rather not have to run Nginx in front to listen to IPv6 traffic.

Config I tried:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: "[::]:4000"]
```

Stack trace (looks like Phoenix only expects an integer port):

```
** (Mix) Could not start application my_app: MyApp.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: MyApp.Endpoint
    ** (EXIT) shutdown: failed to start child: Phoenix.Endpoint.Server
        ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
            ** (ArgumentError) argument error
                :erlang.binary_to_integer("[::]:4000")
                (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/server.ex:32: Phoenix.Endpoint.Server.to_port/1
                (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/server.ex:28: Phoenix.Endpoint.Server.default/3
                (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/server.ex:17: anonymous fn/5 in Phoenix.Endpoint.Server.init/1
                (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1623: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
                (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/server.ex:15: Phoenix.Endpoint.Server.init/1
                (stdlib) supervisor.erl:294: :supervisor.init/1
                (stdlib) gen_server.erl:328: :gen_server.init_it/6
                (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

Also this is Phoenix `{:phoenix, "~> 1.2.0"}` and Cowboy `{:cowboy, "~> 1.0"}`

Comment: Did you try something like `[::]:4000`? See [RFC 5952, Section 6, Notes on Combining IPv6 Addresses with Port Numbers](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952#section-6).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it fails to parse an an integer though. I'll update the question with a little more info including the stack trace.

Comment: First, the application must support IPv6. It appears that this application does not. Contact its developer(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/endpoint.html you can also use just `:inet6`. This works for me:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  http: [:inet6, port: 4000],
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. This happens to work after a couple of my PRs got merged: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/pull/1933 and https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/pull/1934 :)

Answer (score 5):

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4000, ip: {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]
```

This tells Phoenix to listen on all IPv6 addresses. It also listens on IPv4.

I originally thought this was IPv6-only, since `netstat -tulpn` shows `beam` as only `tcp6` and not `tcp`. But after testing, it's clear that it is also listening on IPv4 as an "IPv4-mapped IPv6 address."

The IP tuple format is Erlang type [inet:ip6_address()](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#type-ip6_address).