# Unable to make my application listen on IPv6 interface on localhost

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ipv6

I'm trying to make my application to work on IPv6 while on localhost in the development environment:

```
config :my_app, MyAppWeb.Endpoint,

  http: [port: System.get_env("PORT", "8000"), ip: {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}],
  # http: [:inet6, port: System.get_env("PORT", "8000")],
  # ......
```

Nonetheless, accessing my application IPv6 won't load it:

```
[1111:2222: .....]:8000
```

whereas `localhost:8000` will normally, as always.

How to make it work with IPv6? On localhost, in the dev env.

**update1**

```
  http: [port: System.get_env("PORT", "8000"), ip: "::1"],
```

**still won't work**

**update2**

```
  http: [:inet6, port: System.get_env("PORT", "8000"), ip: "::1"],
```

**still won't work**

---

[How to get Phoenix to listen on IPv6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39606428/how-to-get-phoenix-to-listen-on-ipv6) -- nothing has worked

Answer (score 0):

That is not the IPv6 loopback address, it is the IPv6 unspecified address. You normally configure localhost to a loopback address (an address in the `127.0.0.0/8` IPv4 loopback block, or `::1` for IPv6).

You are trying to use the IPv6 `::` address, but that is basically the same as `0.0.0.0` for IPv4.

Comment: none of the 2 ways  I've tried hasn't worked. Why will `:inet6` not work either?

Comment: how tno specify `::1` there in the config then?

Comment: You are using `ip: {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`, which is all zeros (`::`). Try `ip: {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}`, which is `::1`.

Comment: still no difference; only v4

Comment: So, which is the source IPv6 address you are trying to connect to this?

Comment: what do you mean "which"?

Comment: Are you trying to reach the server application from an address, or are you just trying to loopback inside the host? Looping back, you send to the loopback address (`::1`). I do not understand what this is about: `[1111:2222: .....]:8000`. It looks like you are trying to make up an invalid IPv6 address.

Comment: what's the difference? I'm trying to reach the application from the *outside*, as if it was a remote server in the internet. This has worked well when I run a python server  on my local machine.

Comment: `I do not understand what this is about: [1111:2222: .....]:8000` ---> it's an obfuscated IPv6 address. In really I'm using a real and valid one

Comment: When you want to do something like that, IANA has set aside three IPv4 (`192.0.2.0/24`, `198.51.100.0/24`, and `203.0.113.0/24`) address ranges and one IPv6 (`2001:db8::/32`) address range for example addressing, and you should use addressing from those for your examples so that others can see what that is. When you make up invalid addressing, it looks like you are actually trying to use it. No valid IPv6 address starts with `1111:2222:`. Also, you cannot reach the localhost of a host from outside the host.

Comment: Once again: it's not literally `1111:2222`, nor does it start with it! In reality I'm using a valid ipv6 address!

Comment: My point is that people don not know it is not what you are actually using just by looking at it, and must assume you are doing it wrong. If you use addressing in the IANA ranges set aside for such things, then everyone knows you are just giving an example, not trying to use an invalid address. It avoids such discussions as this where we have to ask if you are using invalid addressing.

Comment: So, you assume that everyone should know the addresses you use are not the addresses you use? IANA set aside ranges specifically for this, and using those tells everyone that they are not what you are using. I do not know why you insist on not using what IANA has given you. After all, you are the one asking for help, and you should take advantage of things like this to get better help, and displaying such an attitude toward those trying to help is counterproductive; you could find your questions ignored..

Answer (score 0):

You can try an empty string like this `""`
use `netstat -ano | findstr LISTEN` to confirm it listening on ipv6

Comment: I'm not asking how to confirm it

Comment: `http: [port: System.get_env("PORT", "8000"), ip: ""]`

Comment: that hasn't worked either